# How to send both integers and floats in the correct way for serial (write) communication in Python 2.7

Tags: python, serialization, hex, ascii, pyserial

I'm struggling with serial write communication. Basically I don't know which option to choose to combine both integers and float values in the correct way for serial write.

The problem: I need to send data values (chars,int, floats) to a microcontroller (ARM8 processor) for control of wheels for a robot platform. By means of a RS422 to USB converter I'm able to read data values from the same microcontroller, by means of this Python code:

```
import serial
from struct import unpack

# Initialization
counter = 0

#open serial for reading (BMW to PC communication)
s_port = 'COM8'
b_rate = 460800
ser = serial.Serial(port=s_port,baudrate=b_rate,timeout=0.01)

#method for reading incoming bytes on serial
while counter<20:
    data = ser.readline()
    data = data.encode("hex")
    strlen = len(data)
    rev_data = "".join(reversed([data[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]))

    if strlen==80:
        Soh = data[0:2]
        Nob = data[2:4]
        Adr = data[4:6]
        Cmd = data[6:8]
        Hrt = data[8:12]
        Po1 = data[12:28]
        Po2 = data[28:44]
        En1 = data[44:60]
        En2 = data[60:76]
        Crc = data[76:78]
        Eot = data[78:80]

        So1 = unpack('B', Soh.decode("hex")) # unsigned char
        No1 = unpack('B', Nob.decode("hex")) # unsigned char
        Ad1 = unpack('B', Adr.decode("hex")) # unsigned char
        Cm1 = unpack('B', Cmd.decode("hex")) # unsigned char
        Hr1 = unpack('h', Hrt.decode("hex")) # short
        Po1 = unpack('d', Po1.decode("hex")) # double
        Po2 = unpack('d', Po2.decode("hex")) # double
        En1 = unpack('d', En1.decode("hex")) # double
        En2 = unpack('d', En2.decode("hex")) # double
        Cr1 = unpack('B', Crc.decode("hex")) # unsigned char
        Eo1 = unpack('B', Eot.decode("hex")) # unsigned char

        StartOfHeader = So1[0]
        NoOfBytes = No1[0]
        Address = Ad1[0]
        Command = Cm1[0]
        Heartbeat = Hr1[0]
        Potentiometer1 = Po1[0]
        Potentiometer2 = Po2[0]
        Encoder1 = En1[0]
        Encoder2 = En2[0]
        CRC = Cr1[0]
        EndOfTransmission = Eo1[0]

        counter = counter+1

ser.close()
```

In Labview the serial write communication is already working, so that is my starting point:

[image: Labview Serial Write code]

But as I need to work with Python the trick is to make it working in Python. 
To my knowledge the data is converted to ASCII, based on the "Type Cast" function in Labview (http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/287D59BAF21F58C786256E8A00520ED5)

Honestly I don't nothing about ASCII messages, so I'm not 100% sure.

Now, I want to do the same trick for the serial write in Python 2.7. Starting from chr,int, float values converting to hexadecimal string and then write to the serial port. **I suppose to use an ASCII conversion at the end, but I don't know if it's ASCII and the right Python command to do the conversion in the right way.**

This is my serial write coding in Python so far (excuse me, for the long and inefficient coding lines):

```
# Initialization
counter = 0

#open serial for reading (BMW to PC communication)
s_port = 'COM9'
b_rate = 460800
ser = serial.Serial(port=s_port,baudrate=b_rate,timeout=0.05)

#method for writing to serial
while counter<100:
    Soh = chr(1)
    Nob = chr(46)
    Adr = chr(49)
    Cmd = chr(32)
    DFS = float(1)
    DRS = float(2)
    DFD = int(3)
    DRD = int(4)
    DFC = int(5)
    DRC = int(6)
    SFCP = float(7)
    SRCP = float(8)
    SFC = int(9)
    SRC = int(10)
    CRC = chr(77)
    EOT = chr(4)

    S1 = Soh.encode("hex")
    N1 = Nob.encode("hex")
    A1 = Adr.encode("hex")
    C1 = Cmd.encode("hex")
    D11 = hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', DFS))[0])
    D1 = D11[2:]
    D12 = hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', DRS))[0])
    D2 = D12[2:]
    D3 = '{0:08x}'.format(DFD)
    D4 = '{0:08x}'.format(DRD)
    D5 = '{0:08x}'.format(DFC)
    D6 = '{0:08x}'.format(DRC)
    S11 = hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', SFCP))[0])
    S2 = S11[2:]
    S12 = hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', SRCP))[0])
    S3 = S12[2:]
    S4 = '{0:08x}'.format(SFC)
    S5 = '{0:08x}'.format(SRC)
    C2 = CRC.encode("hex")
    E1 = EOT.encode("hex")

    hex_string = E1 + C2 + S5 + S4 + S3 + S2 + D6 + D5 + D4 + D3 + D2 + D1 + C1 + A1 + N1 + S1
    rev_hex_string = "".join(reversed([hex_string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex_string), 2)]))

    ##command = ...

    ser.write(command)
    counter = counter+1

ser.close()
```

This Python code generates the same hexadecimal string (called rev_hex_string) as the Labview programm. But till now, I was unable to do the serial write with Python.

**I don't know how to proceed. Do I need ASCII for serial write? And which Python codes to use? encode("ascii"), decode("hex")? I'm totally lost in the many possibilities....**

In case I use encode("ascii") or decode("hex") in Python it only generates a " .01" (ASCII???) message.

When I switch the normal view in Labview it has a much longer message:
" .01   €?   @        |   -   à@   A   M" 
(I still missing some characters, but this is the most)

*Besides that; do I need carriage returns and/or buffer flushing?*

I have to say I'm new to serial write communication. I hope you can help me.

Sorry for the long post, I hope to be as precise as possible.

Comment: In Python you can type cast numeric values into ascii strings by using the builit-in [`str`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) class. i.e. `str(3.1415)` -> `'3.1415'`. Likewise, if you have an ascii string, you can go in the opposite direction with `float('3.1415')` -> `3.1415`.

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to start with something simpler. Most machines allow for querying their version number or have an echo function. First get that working.